# Converting variables in form of "2015M01" to date format in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a date frame `df` that simply looks like this:

```
 month  values
2012M01  99904
2012M02  99616
2012M03  99530
2012M04  99500
2012M05  99380
2012M06  99103
2013M01  98533
2013M02  97600
2013M03  96431
2013M04  95369
2013M05  94527
2013M06  93783
```

with month that was written in form of "M01", "M02"... and so on. 
 Now I want to convert this column to date format, is there a way to do it in R with lubridate?

I also want to select columns that contain one certain month from each year, like only March columns from all these years, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why not remove the character "M"? `lubridate::fast_strptime(gsub('M','',df$month),'%Y%m')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that dates require a year, month and day, so you cannot convert directly to a date format. You have 2 options.

Option 1: convert to a year-month format using `zoo::as.yearmon`.

```
library(zoo)
df$yearmon <- as.yearmon(df$month, "%YM%m")
# you can get e.g. month from that
months(df$yearmon[1])
# [1] "January"
```

Option 2: convert to a date by assuming that the day is always the first day of the month.

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$month, "01", sep = "-"), "%YM%m-%d")
```

For selection (and I think you mean select rows, not columns), you already have everything you need. For example, to select only March 2013:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(month == "2013M03")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! both works fine. And yes, it is rows with specific months that I want to select.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this will get it:

```
raw <- "2012M01"

dt <- strptime(raw,format = "%YM%m")
```

dt will be in a Posix format.  The strptime function will assign a '1' as the default day of month to make it a complete date.

Comment: No because a) `strptime()` is not a part of lubridate so your library call is spurious and b) more importantly, a year and month do NOT make a date -- as has been answered here a dozen or more times.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I cleaned up the answer that I had provided.